# Redirecting in express doesn't go to a different url (node.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am using Express in node.js

From my client side, I have a jQuery

```
$.get('/signUp', function(data) {
    document.write(data);
});
```

and in one of my routers, I have this

```
router.get('/signUp', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/signUpPage');
});
```

The sign up page is also a route.
I read some uses of redirect but the solutions are not working or not exactly for express, what my code does is it goes to the signUpPage but the url in the address bar does not change. What can I do to make the url {baseURL}/signUpPage?

Problem solved. 
I used window.location.assign('/signUpPage') on the client side.

Comment: `$.get()` performs an AJAX request. Any redirects that are sent back as a result of it will not cause the current browser page to be changed; only the AJAX request itself will be redirected to the new URL.

Comment: @robertklep Thank you. But I wonder how can I change the browser page knowing that my page is written using a router?.

Comment: Instead of a redirect being issues from `/signUp`, you could return a JSON document "telling" the client that it should redirect (using `window.location` to change the page).